# C# How to remove char from LinkedList of chars to a char variable?

Tags: c#, linked-list

Following code results with error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'char'

```
    string S = "Hello World!";        
    LinkedList<char> myChars = new LinkedList<char>();

    foreach (char ch in S)
    {
        myChars.AddFirst(ch);
    }

    char c = myChars.RemoveFirst();
```

How can I remove first element and copy it to a char variable c?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var node = myChars.First;
char c = node.Value;
myChars.Remove(node);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was learning this from Java example and I must notice that it is much easier in Java... myChars.Remove(n); n = index of element (in this case 0)

Comment: @DanielHamilton, it's true that it would be nice if `RemoveFirst` returned the first node, or the first value; but on the other hand, it doesn't make much sense to access linked list elements by index.